# Java2D light with AlphaComposite and Color

Tags: java, awt, game-engine, java-2d, light

**NOTE:** If anything is unclear and keeps you from answering, please write a comment and let me know!

I am trying to create light in my Java2D game engine (plain Java - no OpenGl or something) and it works fine, but the light is only white even when I give it a Color. 
The way I create light:

1. Draw the game
2. Draw a black rectangle over everything
3. Set the `Composite` of the `Graphics2D` to `AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_OUT, compositeAlpha)` with `compositeAlpha` being a custom float between 0f and 1f.
4. Draw some stuff in a Color.

What happens is, that what I draw after setting the composite, cuts out of the black rectangle and you can see the stuff under it.
[A red small circle and a white big circle both with a `RadialGradientPaint`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsKTF.png). The problem is obvious; the **red circle** in the top right corner **is not red**.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
private void updateLightMap() {
    Graphics2D graphics = lightMap.createGraphics();
    graphics.clearRect(0, 0, lightMap.getWidth(), lightMap.getHeight());
    graphics.setColor(lightMapColor);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, lightMap.getWidth(), lightMap.getHeight());
    Composite oldComp = graphics.getComposite();
    graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_OUT, compositeAlpha));

    graphics.setRenderingHints(Game.getHost().getRenderHints());

    lights.forEach(light -> light.draw(graphics));

    graphics.setComposite(oldComp);
    graphics.dispose();
}

@Override
public void draw(SaltyGraphics saltyGraphics) {
    updateLightMap();
    saltyGraphics.drawImage(lightMap, Vector2f.zero());
}
```

How I draw the circles:

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D graphics2D) {
    graphics2D.setColor(lightColor);
    graphics2D.setPaint(ColorUtil.createRadialGradientPaint(getTransform(), lightColor, targetAlpha));
    graphics2D.fillOval(Math.round(getX()), Math.round(getY()), Math.round(getWidth()), Math.round(getHeight()));
}
```

With for the one, `lightColor` is white, for the other red.

Am I using the wrong AlphaComposite? With `AlphaComposite.SrcOver`, the red circle is red, but you can't see the underlying stuff anymore.

Complete code on github (https://github.com/edgelord314/salty-engine/tree/light), relevant classes:

1. `Scene` in `de.edgelord.saltyengine.scene` (the last view lines of the method `draw(SaltyGraphics)`)
2. `LightSystem` in `de.edgelord.saltyengine.cosmetic.light`
3. `Light` in `de.edgelord.saltyengine.cosmetic.light`
4. `PointLight` in `de.edgelord.saltyengine.cosmetic.light`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson , thanks. I'll edit the question :)